# Tracking Android Market statistics

Tags: android, statistics, google-play

The developer console provides basic install statistics but does not provide any historical data or graphs. Many sites (androidzoom.com and many more) provide a view of the Market but they seem to be very out of date and generally provide much less granular data.

Is there any way to access the data Google already has on my application and display it usefully or will I have to look at tracking statistics myself /using Analytics?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Developer Console at http://market.android.com there is a "statistics" link underneath the number of active installs for each app.  Clicking that will bring up the historical installation data, as well as graphs and tables by platform version, device, country, and so on.

You can go straight there with a link like

https://market.android.com/publish/Home#ViewStatisticPlace:p=YOURPACKAGENAME

where YOURPACKAGENAME would be the com.whatever.whatever for your application.